# Having troubles with my swagger placeholder description

Tags: spring, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, sts

I have a problem with the description of the placeholders, the parameters appear duplicate and separate as you can see in this image:

[image: Swagger placeholder]

This is my controller:
[image: post endpoint]

And this controllers is linked to a service class.
I want to have the placeholder with the name of the parameter only one time and without dash (`-`).

Answer (score 0):

This is a description combined of your parameter name and value or a representation of your parameter example. You can use `@ApiParam` to change placeholder inside your filed.

Example:

```
@GetMapping("/clients/{uid}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getClient(@ApiParam(value = "An String value representing a User ID." ,  example = "a12") @PathVariable String uid)
```

Or

```
@GetMapping("/clients/{uid}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getClient(@ApiParam(value = "An String value representing a User ID.") @PathVariable String uid)
```